# I2C between Yun Shield (Dragino) and UNO R3 problem

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-yun, wire-library

I am having problems with I2C communications between my Dragino Yun and an Arduino UNO R3.

I can have the Dragino request data (using `Wire.onRequest` on UNO) from the UNO and it works great, however, when I have the UNO sending and the Dragino using `Wire.onReceive` it's not picking up any data!?

What are the SDA and SCL pins on the Dragino? Are they the same as the UNO? Are there any specific difficulties involved for this setup?